# Okta Custom Attribute per each application

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have a question, can i have the same Custom Attribute for User Profile, but different value per each application that User have

Example:

App1
  **Name**:John Test
  **ApplicationRole**: Admin

App2
  **Name**: John Test
  **ApplicationRole**: Cashier


or i need to create one Custom Attribute for each App?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Value for custom attribute created in Okta profile will be global for each user in Okta. So you cannot do it that way.

What you need is custom attribute per app. However, admin would need to set those two custom attribute values for same user per app. Or you could use API call to do it. Lets say your custom attribute for each app is called ApplicationRole. Assuming same user is assigned to both app. In that case.

For App1

/api/v1/apps//users/

{
  "profile": {
      "ApplicationRole": "Admin"
    }
}

For App2

/api/v1/apps//users/

{
  "profile": {
      "ApplicationRole": "Cashier"
    }
}